# Expected time for random process

Tags: probability

I have a process that runs like this. Each step takes expected time $\sqrt{n} \exp\left\{\cfrac{-t^2}{2n}\right\}$ where $t$ is the total length of time of all the previous steps added together.  I would like to know the expected time that $x$ steps will take. Is this enough information to solve the problem?

If I knew the distribution $P(X_t \geq x)$ how could I then solve the problem? Let us say $X_t$ is the time needed for a step that starts at time $t$.

Comment: Is $n$ a constant, or is it referring to the $n$'th step?

Comment: Perhaps rewriting this to a recursive relation allows you to come up with a direct formula.

Comment: No, it's not enough information. Since the function isn't linear in $t$, it's not enough to know the expected duration of the previous steps; you need to know the distribution of their duration.

Comment: @RobertIsrael $n$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, for two steps you are given $E[T_1]$ and $E[T_2 | T_1] = 
\sqrt{n} \exp\left(-T_1^2/(2n)\right)$.  So $E[T_1 + T_2] = E[T_1] + E\left[ \sqrt{n} \exp\left( - T_1^2/(2n)\right)\right]$.  But for that you need to know more about the distribution of $T_1$, not just its expected value.  So you don't have enough information.

Comment: You understood perfectly. If you have the distribution how would you solve the problem?